# Datatables.net rowreorder issue with internet explorer

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, internet-explorer, datatables

I have a .Net Core 3.1 mvc app that is loading a partial after the initial page load. In that partial there is a Datatables.net table that is using the `datatables.net-rowreorder/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min.js` library.

This works fine in firefox/chrome but in IE 11 I get an error

```
SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier
jquery.js (328,5)
```

and I have narrowed it down to a event listener I have on my datatable but I am not sure how to resolve for IE.

Here is the javascript inside my partial view.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var categories = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model))');
    categoryTable = $('#categoryTable').DataTable({
        dom: 't',
        data: categories,
        paging: false,
        autoWidth: false,
        rowId: 'id',
        rowReorder: {
            selector: 'tr',
            dataSrc: 'order'
        },
        columns: [
            // code here
        ]
    });

    categorytable.on('row-reorder', function (e, diff, edit) {
        for (let [key, value] of object.entries(edit.values)) {
            $.get("/controller/action?id=" + key + "&newordervalue=" + value);
        }
    });
});
```

the last part is what is throwing the error and causing the entire table not to render.

If anyone knows why this is an issue in IE it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try to store the "/controller/action?id=" + key + "&newordervalue=" + value in variable and try to pass the variable in the $.get(). See if it makes any difference. Try to replace the 'let' with the 'var' in the for loop and check whether it fix this issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I narrowed it down a bit more and it does seem to be that `for` loop that is breaking in IE. I updated it to use `var` over `let` and still no luck, I commented out the `.get()` for testing so it isn't that call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following syntax works in both IE and chrome

```
categoryTable.on('row-reorder', function (e, diff, edit) {
    var result = 'Reorder started on row: '+edit.triggerRow.data().description+'<br>';
    console.log(result);

    for ( var i=0, ien=diff.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
        var rowData = categoryTable.row( diff[i].node ).data();
        var result = rowData.description+' updated to be in position '+
            diff[i].newData + ' (was ' + diff[i].oldData + ')<br>';

        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/examples/initialisation/events.html

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.